# CSS flexbox child stretch and text overflow cut off issue

Tags: css, flexbox, overflow

I'm having an issue with flexbox and overflow, below is a fiddle that shows my issue:

https://jsfiddle.net/hcvq7pm9/

So basically I'm trying to achieve a text ellipsis overflow which works if we set the `.aside > .right` to `overflow: hidden`. However this has the side effect of cutting off overflow such as the button box shadow.

If we comment out the overflow:

https://jsfiddle.net/mdykhx3q/

The button shadow is now fine and shows correctly, but we have lost the overflow on the text and child stretches out. I have tried wrapping the text with it's own div and associated CSS but that does not work.

https://jsfiddle.net/guxehft2/

Does anyone know how this can be solved. Basically need that `.aside > .right` element to not stretch out but stay in the bounds of the parent `.aside` which does have an explicit width...

Answer (score 0):

The content seems to be ok, but rather dealing with the outline on the box model of the button.

The shadow of the button sits within the margin of the box model and therefore is subject to being cut out when using `overflow: hidden`.

I would recommend adding margin of the same size as the shadow or outline if you choose to use it, such as:

```
button {
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 0.2rem rgb(38 143 255 / 50%);
  margin: 0.2rem;
}
```

Comment: Yes, same answer as I gave to previous, so you can put a padding on the box or margin on the button, but this really messes with the spacing model.

Answer (score 0):

Additional to @ashmatty:

Another solution would be to add padding to the parent grid container if the grid-system allows space between the columns. So the left edge of the button (without shaddow) is justified to the left egde of the text above:

```
.aside > .right { padding[-top|-right|-bottom|-left]: 0.2rem }
```

Comment: Yes, unfortunately, this really messes with spacing, and I would have to change the whole model around that, which really complicates things further.